# Formatting a 2d int array into a string using streams

Tags: java, java-stream, tostring, collect

I have the following array:

```
private static final int[][] BOARD = {
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};
```

And I want to create a String representation on it, so if I were to print it on the console, it should look like this:

```
[0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0]
```

I can get this done with 2 nested `for` loops, but I am trying to accomplish this using streams. This is what I got so far:

```
public String toString() {
    StringJoiner board = new StringJoiner("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD.length; i++) {
        board.add(
            IntStream.of(BOARD[i])
                .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]"))
        );
    }
    return board.toString();
}
```

Is this something possible? I'm not particularly interested in performance (feel free to add some comments on that regard if you want), I am just trying to do this in a single chain of stream operations.

Comment: `Arrays.stream(BOARD).map(Arrays::toString).map(row -> row.replace(" ", "")).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest the `stream` and map each level together, first by commas and then by the system line separator. Like,

```
return Arrays.stream(BOARD).map(a -> Arrays.stream(a)
            .mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]")))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
```

I get

```
[0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can alternatively do it using [`Arrays.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(int%5B%5D))as :

```
Arrays.stream(BOARD)
        .map(aBOARD -> IntStream.of(aBOARD)
                .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]")))
        .forEach(board::add);
```

Answer (score 0):

Collections' `toString()` already provides that notation in the [AbstractCollection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()) class. Just use:-

```
Arrays.stream(BOARD)
        .forEach(ints -> System.out.println(
                Arrays.stream(ints).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()))
        );
```

Or if you are happy to change `int[][]` to `Integer[][]`, you can even do:-

```
Arrays.stream(BOARD)
        .forEach(ints -> System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ints)));
```